# Stop automount of new loop device on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: automount, udisks, loop-device

When creating a new loop device with `udisksctl` (command below), I want Ubuntu to only create the device without mounting it automatically. How do I do this on Ubuntu 22.04, and why did this work on Ubuntu 20.04?

With 22.04, Ubuntu automatically also mounts the device (containing an ext4 partition) to somewhere in `/media` on creation. This might happen because there is some configuration to allow automount for devices with `ext4` partitions. If so, what file controls this config?

Curiously, with 20.04, the behavior was different. I had to separately call `udisksctl` (command below) to mount the new device.

Note, I really require separate mounting and device creation commands, since I am creating a script and I need to know the path to the newly mounted device, which is not shown when automount happens.

### Commands

Loop device creation:

`udisksctl loop-setup -f <diskimage.img> --offset=<partition offset>`

Device mounting command

`udisksctl mount -b <loopdev path>`

Comment: As far i know the mountpoint is the same /media/$USER/filesystem -uuid/or lable-of-filesystem.

Comment: You are correct about the mount point. My question was on how to prevent/control automount.